# how to lose fat hips after weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, body-fat, muscle-gain, hip

Here is my "chronological weight loss": when I was 23 I weighed 103 kg then I started to walk long distances (sometimes 10 km per day and 3 times a week). I also decreased food rations (1/3 of what I was eating before), with no cola (no cola for real), no sugar in my coffee, etc. After that I lost 35 or 40 kilos (I weighed 67 kg after 2 years so I was 25 years old) but now I'm 28 and 75 kg. What I see when I face the glass is that I have fat hips! If you see only my face or legs and you just see my hips separately you would say that it's not the same body! So I'm a skinny fat.

If me and my brother we eat same things, I gain weight and not him! Even if we eat something not much fat!

I do not have enough muscles it's obvious.

I'm wondering what kind of "sport" I can do to gain muscle and lose fat hips?

I'm open to any suggestions.

Note that I'm a "good" amateur runner (I can run 30-45min and for about 3-4 times a week). I walk a lot too (7-8 km a day).

Thank you.

Comment: Are you female?

Comment: Hi, no i'm a man, is there a difference (i mean for losing hips fat) ?

Comment: You cannot target where you lose fat. This is called "spot reduction" and it doesn't exist. Your genes are responsible for where your body stores fat, and it's the same thing for losing fat. It's pretty much a "first on, last off" type situation. So if the first place you get fat is your belly, it's probably going to be the last place to lose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your body type is **the pear**
[image]

So your hips will be the last zone where you will losing fat. You just need to loose enough to hips began to slim down.

As far as I understand, most of your workouts are cardio (running and walking). So you need to add some strength exercises. And at the same time, you do not need to grow big muscles and just burn fat.

The best way is to mix strength and cardio exercises and do it in a short interval of time. It is called HIIT ([High Intensity Interval Training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_interval_training)). You can do it at home, and it usually takes about 20 minutes, but it has long lasting fat-burning effect.
You can find many workouts on [XHIT Daily](https://www.youtube.com/user/XFitDaily) Youtube channel.

Just do not start with very intensive workouts.
If you are newbie, you can start with the mix of pilates and HIIT.
See the most popular fitness blog on Youtube for women - [Blogilates](https://www.youtube.com/user/blogilates).

Answer (score 1):

Losing weight and losing fat are most often going hand by hand. Sometimes stress can be a very big factor that stops us from achieving our goals, as well as not getting enough sleep. Make sure to stay hydrated and don't drink too much alcohol. I used to struggle with fat in some areas but I found out that I had to be calmer during the whole time. Then I started seeing results. Do not compare yourself to anybody else and don't do too much cardio. Generally lifting weights a couple of times a week and doing a moderate amount of cardio will do the work. But don't forget to eat clean! That's what matters most. Most of the questions here are regarding losing fat from a specific area. It's your body that decides from which area you will lose fat. You can only help it by adjusting your training and nutrition properly. 
I hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 1):

The most stubborn fat in the majority of women is lower body subcutaneous fat around the hip, butt and thighs. Hormones make women likely to deposit fat around the hips to support childbirth and lactation. Countering nature and losing fat from the hips specifically is challenging.

Comment: This is more commentary than answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share with you one of the websites I follow. 
[Bodybuilding](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/goulet5.htm)

In this case I shared a post about Muscle toning because is the first approach we all think inmediatly when we read your case. It's easy to end up suggesting to you to do aerobic workouts, low weight and many reps. But It's not allways that simple.

Body is not just a bunch of muscles. Everything matters. The point is to find out a balanced diet / workout routine.

To do thousand times the very same workouts for ages wont end up as expected.

In bottom lines:

Trainning goes through different statges. The first one use to be Cut Trainning. Oriented to cutdow our weight. Fatburn routine plus hypocaloric diets.

Next stage use to be a strengh trainning. In order to achive a toned shape, both woman and man should not be afraid to lift weight. Intensity here matters, so don't be afraid to lift weight (enough to make you feel unconfortable but still doable). Many reps. 10-12, 12-15 depends the muscle group we are exercising.

Goal here is to gain muscle.

Circuits are just great at this stage. Working intensely mltiple muscle groups.

Any aerobic activity should be moderated. Low-mid intensity. Otherwise we may end up burning muscle.

Here diet changes too. It's hypercaloric. To gain muscle demans calories.

I would like to be able to say all the workouts you should to do, but there's not a universal routine or plan valid for everyone :-).

Now that you are familiar with the 2 stages that matters (in your case), see a personal trainner or trainner at gym.
Ask for a customized plan. Don't miss any muscle ;-) From shoulders to toes, going through shoulders, chest, arms, abs, back, low back, buttocks, legs...

In 6-8 weeks review your plan and change it. It's important to change it over time.

Don't be shy!!! Google any doubt and ask your trainner. She/he is probably the best one you can ask to.

:-)

Hope it helps.

It may seems hard or too complexe but it's not. Just don't give up!